# Get consecutive numbers Range from SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. I have a Table having Column `BookNo` as `datatype int`. This column contains below data

```
|BookNo|
1
2
3
4
5
10
12
13
25
26
27
28
```

I want to the Consecutive Numbers Range in Sql query. From above data my output should be like

```
1 to 5
10 to 13
25 to 28
```

Any Help...

Comment: So I think you should also have `11` in your sample data ;).

Comment: Yes,  but its type is different... The Data i have provided is of `not Issued books`.. the missing number are `Issued`..

Comment: `(1 ),
(2 ),
(3 ),
(4 ),
(5 ),
(10),
(12),
(13),
(19),
(20),
(25),
(26),
(27),
(28)` what will be the expected result for these values

Comment: I need it Range wise @tinka, i have provided my required Output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT BookNo, ISNULL(LEAD(prev) OVER (ORDER BY BookNo) , (SELECT MAX(BookNo) FROM yourTable)) As toCon
FROM
    (
    SELECT *, LAG(BookNo) OVER (ORDER BY BookNo) prev, BookNo - LAG(BookNo) OVER (ORDER BY BookNo) diff
    FROM yourTable) dt
WHERE 
    (ISNULL(diff, 0) <> 1);
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4a29/1)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution based on *Windowed Aggregate Functions* which also runs on versions below SS2014 (and should perform better than the `LAG`/`LEAD`):

```
SELECT MIN(BookNo) AS BookNoFrom, MAX(BookNo) AS BookNoTo
FROM
  (
    SELECT BookNo, 
        BookNo - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BookNo) AS dummy
    FROM yourTable
  ) dt
GROUP BY dummy
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf321/1)

The `dummy` calculation is based on the fact that both `BookNo` and `ROW_NUMBER` are sequential numbers, but there might be gaps in the `BookNo`. For consecutive `BookNo` the difference is always the same, when there's a gap it increases (the `dummy` value has no actual meaning, but it's the same value for consecutive rows).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is Books:

```
;with MainCTE as (
    /*Left Join to get the Last Continous number (Like 5,13,28)*/
    select c1.BookNo as lst, c1.BookNo as previous from Books c1 left join Books c2 on  c1.BookNo+1 = c2.BookNo 
    where c2.BookNo is null 
    /*Union all to make recusion and get the previous contionous number*/
    /*Note: i returned the lst number as it is. only i changed the previous number*/
        union all
            select MainCTE.lst,Books.BookNo from MainCTE inner join Books on MainCTE.previous = Books.BookNo+ 1
)
select min(previous),max(lst) from MainCTE
group by lst
```